# Images not being found moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am doing some moodle development and have pulled down an existing moodle and set it up on my local machine.

The site runs fine apart from no images display

I am running the site locally as moodle-hy:8080.

The images that are being fetched however are looking at

```
GET http://localhost:8888/pluginfile.php/107/mod_label/intro/elearning.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Moodle stores all the images in the database and I know there is a missing link in the chain I just cant figure out where it is.

Comment: What happens if you try this `http://localhost/pluginfile.php/` ?

Comment: moodle-hy:8080/pluginfile.php/ Takes me a to a page that says "No valid arguments supplied or incorrect server configuration"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds to me like you've got a missing dependency. Could you please double check that your virtual server has the correct version of PHP, and all the Moodle essentials... Especially any PHP addons that are to do with image compression.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth pointing out you may need to run the database search and replace script, at:

http://my-public-ip/moodle/admin/tool/replace/index.php

as referenced in Method 2 [here](https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Moodle_migration).

This is required if you change the name of the site once you have installed it. If you were already using Moodle under "localhost", then there will be a number of references to the old localhost address stored in the database that need to be updated to the new moodle-hy address.